# Rewrite a URL in nginx without redirecting

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'm trying to create a rewrite with nginx that will change the displayed URL without actually redirecting to it. EG: `http://example.com/item/rest-of-path`  would become `http://example.com/folder/rest-of-path`. I've been working with different variations of this code with in my nginx.conf:

```
location ~ /example {
   rewrite ^/example/(.*) /folder/$1 last;
}
```

but that doesn't seem to be doing the trick. Any ideas where I'm going wrong here? I'll admit I'm still pretty new to server-side rewrites in general.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
location ~ /example {
   rewrite ^/example/(.*) /folder/$1 break;
}
```

use `break`.

Comment: This won't "change the displayed URL without actually redirecting to it.".

Answer (score -1):

Try this. It isn't necessary to place it under the `location` block, and don't forget to reload nginx.

```
rewrite     ^/example/(.+)$     /folder/$1 last;
```